# use of the definite article in context

Tags: articles, definite-article

Tell me please if need to use *the* in the following sentence.

> A lot of guys are lagging in (**the**) upper chest development, which leads to an unproportionally developed chest.

I am in doubt because on one hand the word *development* in this context appeares to be a countable noun, and on the other hand the words *upper* and *chest* specify which development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English speakers will overwhelmingly say 'lagging in upper chest development' without using 'the', if 'upper chest' comes first. If 'development' comes first  (e.g. '(The) development of the upper chest is important for power lifters'), some people will put 'the' before 'development' but most probably would not.

Also, If some parts of the chest are well developed and others are not so well developed, most people would refer to a 'disproportionately developed chest' rather than an 'unproportionally developed chest'. If the chest is poorly developed overall, it would be referred to as 'an undeveloped chest'.